# debug javascript function on chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Two Questions about debugging in chrome console :

1. How can I debug function that I am writing directly in the chrome console on the fly ?
   for example

> ```
> function say(){
> console.log("hello");
> console.log("test");
> }
> ```

I want to set breakpoints,etc..

And how can I do a tab in a console for indention?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

#### 1.Someone may have a better solution. Try:

```
debugger;say()
```

in your console, and then press F11 twice, you will be navigated to a VMxxxx tab, you can add breakpoints there and it will be kept.

i.e. next time you run `say()` in the console, the breakpoint will be triggered.

#### 2.I haven't figured out a way to do it either, but you may try `Shift+Enter` to open a new line and ident with spaces, or copy a "tab" from somewhere else (a text editor) and paste it in chrome.

Comment: What is "press f11 twice" on OS X?

Answer (score 7):

Now you can write functions and debug them in Chrome console directly.

**Chrome Dev Tools -> Sources -> Snippets

You can write any code there, set breakpoints and hit Ctrl + Enter to run it.

Comment: Where did you find New Script? There is just Open File

Comment: Open File is in the hamburger menu of the Sources. content Scripts is hidden behind the double arrow.

Comment: This is now under snippets, next to Scripts in the double arrow Sources menu

Comment: When I tried this the breakpoints weren't hit - there must be some trick?

Comment: Each time you run a snippet it runs in a separate vm. There should be a tab for the vm. You can set the break point there.

Answer (score 5):

Now you could use `debug()`.

```js
debug(say)
```

> [Console Utilities API Reference  |  Tools for Web Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#debug)

Comment: Amazing! Works. Next time function gets called it goes to debugger;

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the given answer by Kevin, here is the deal:

the command `debugger;` will trigger the **PAUSE** into debugger sources window.

You may change your function to

```
function say(){
  debugger;
  console.log("hello");
  console.log("test");
}
```

and next time you execute the **function** `say()` it will pause at the beginning.

You may also type `debugger;say();` in the console because it will pause before calling the function say() but you have to press F11 to **Setp Into The Next Function**

Answer (score 0):

Snippet can also be used for this purpose. Though snippets are shared across pages and run from the context of current open page but can be used for this purpose as well.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick, navigate to the following

**Chrome Dev Tools -> Sources -> Snippet -> New snippet**

Give it a name to the snippet, And add the script in the editor (right side panel) then save it with CTRL + S.

Now that your snippet is added, you can **right click** on the newly added snippet and click on  **-> Run**

Add the breakpoint and call the method, once debugging is done you can remove the snippet, Incase, if you have trouble creating Snippet check this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets)